# Clear one redux state on page transition

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I'm creating a notification state like this (in redux),

```
import { STORE_NOTIF, PURGE_NOTIF } from '../actions/notif';

const defaultState = {
  kind: null,
  message: null
}

export default function notifReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case STORE_NOTIF:
    return {kind: action.kind, message: action.message};
  case PURGE_NOTIF:
    return defaultState;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

this works for events I know to control. But where should I implement the clearing (PURGE_NOTIF) for when I transition to pages, say from sign-in to home page? I don't want to write a `componentWillMount` (and I don't think that's the write way) on every component to clear the `notifState`. Should this be like somewhere in the routes? I use react-router BTW.

**UPDATE** with answer

My new reducer looks like this where I added a `displayed` boolean

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import { STORE_NOTIF, PURGE_NOTIF, DISPLAY_NOTIF } from '../actions/notif';

const defaultState = {
  kind: null,
  message: null,
  displayed: true
}

export default function notifReducer(state = defaultState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case STORE_NOTIF:
    return _.merge({}, state, { kind: action.kind, message: action.message, displayed: action.displayImmediately });
  case DISPLAY_NOTIF:
    return _.merge({}, state, { displayed: true });
  case PURGE_NOTIF:
    return defaultState;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

and in my client is where I check if it's been displayed already or not and handle appropriately.

```
const scrollTop = () => { window.scrollTo(0, 0) }
const handleNotifs = (store) => {
  const notifState = store.getState().notifState;

  if (notifState.message) {
    if (notifState.displayed) {
      store.dispatch({type: PURGE_NOTIF});
    } else {
      store.dispatch({type: DISPLAY_NOTIF});
    }
  }
}

const store = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore)(reducer, initialState);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router onUpdate={() => {scrollTop(); handleNotifs(store)}} routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your React Router routes using *plain route objects*, you can define lifecycle events on your route. The simplest way to achieve what you described is to specify `onLeave` on the route.

```js
const onLeave = () => store.dispatch({type: "PURGE_NOTIF"})
const routes = (
  {path: "/login", component: LoginPage, onLeave}
)
```

You need to pass a reference to `store` to your `routes`. Here is a possible solution:

```js
// index.js
const store = createStore(/* ... */)
const routes = createRoutes(store)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={routes} />
  </Provider>
)

// createRoutes.js
export default store => {
  const purge = () => store.dispatch({type: "PURGE_NOTIF"})

  return (
    {path: "/", component: Application, childRoutes: [
      {path: "login", component: LoginPage, onLeave: purge},
      {path: "dashboard", component: Dashboard},
    ]}
  )
}
```

Comment: Yep I have it like that. But it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined`. Even if I have `<Provider store={store}>`. How do I access store?

Comment: You have to pass the reference to your current file

Comment: Do I need to export store? From my client I have `const store = applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore)(reducer, initialState);` and `ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0);} routes={routes} history={browserHistory} /></Provider>, document.getElementById('app'));`

Comment: @index I've added details to my answer

Comment: I see. So I need to make my routes part a function so I can pass store. I'll try that out. But I was thinking... if I need it to work on all routes, do I add it to the main route? and `onUpdate` since it won't be leaving? Like this? `<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0); store.dispatch({type: "PURGE_NOTIF"});} routes={routes} history={browserHistory} />`?

Comment: Probably, but you probably won’t want to do that for query changes. Not sure if those go though `onUpdate`.

Comment: Hi @DanAbramov I haven't tried it on queries but so far it's okay for what I initially intended it. One big problem though is when I set a notif to be displayed after an action and moves to the NEXT PAGE. Haha! It purges notification before I could display it. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Dispatch after the route has been left?

Comment: @DanAbramov Hrmn... my `dispatch(notifAction)` is at the component before `browserHistory.push` then it updates and `purge`s the notif... How should I approach that?

Comment: @DanAbramov I've added a tag on my notifs to determine if display now or display later (displayed). And in `onUpdate` I check if I have displayed it or not and display and toggle displayed if not or purge it if I did already. Updated question to show answer.